# How to support `?`/`FromResidual` for custom result enum?

Tags: rust

I would like to save entity in database in case of some specific errors and it seems nice to use custom result enum for this which should rethrow `Err` and `SaveOnErr` when `?` is used.

I've tried to copy `FromResidual` trait from `Result` which seems responsible for `?` usage, but was unsuccessful, is it possible to do?

```
#[derive(Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Debug, Clone)]
pub enum SavableResult<T, E> {
    Ok(T),
    Err(E),
    SaveOnErr(E),
}

fn test1() {
    let result = test2();

    match result {
        SavableResult::Ok(_) | SavableResult::SaveOnErr(_) => save(),
        SavableResult::Err(_) => {}
    };
}
fn test2() -> SavableResult<(), ApiErr> {
    test3()?; // not working

    SavableResult::Ok(())
}
fn test3() -> SavableResult<(), ApiErr> {
    SavableResult::Ok(())
}
fn save() {
    // save in db
}
```

Specific issue that I want to solve:

```
pub async fn execute(&self) -> Result<JwtTokensPair, ApiErr> {
    let mut auth = AuthRepository::get_by_user_id(user_id, &trx).await?;

    // in case of incorrect password `auth` entity `failed_auth_count`
    // is incremented and I need to save it in database anyway
    // to block any auth after 10 fails for hour
    // but only for one specific error
    let result = auth.login(&self.password, self.hash_service);

    // problem here is that it's easy to forget which
    // entities have this special requirement
    // or use this ugly match everywhere
    match result {
        Ok(_)
        | Err(ApiErr {
            save_on_err: true, ..
        }) => AuthRepository::save(&auth, &trx).await?,
        Err(_) => {}
    };
    trx.commit().await?;

    result
}
```

Comment: this seems to break idiomatic rust - can you use an enum for the error type?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, I can and this is what I currently do, but I would like to use custom enum not to forget save operation which possible by setting return type on `test1` fn as `Result<(), ApiErr>` which will force me to convert, otherwise I may accidently rethrow

Comment: Custom types in `?` are currently nightly-only. Why won't you use standard `Result`, with an inner enum for the `Err` variant?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman added specific example, problem is that I want to enforce saving on some specific errors in elegant way, which is currently looks ugly for me and not restricted

Comment: If you want to retain generic errors, then you can `E: SomeTrait` and define the functionality you need (such as `should_save(&self)`) on `SomeTrait`.

Comment: You can make it an enum containing the error, instead of a `bool` struct field, then you will be required to match on it to access the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-question-mark-operator), you cannot overload the `?` operator at this time. Perhaps you could write some sort of conversion that takes your values to a `Result<T, E>`.